# How to not reload my page when I open up my console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-console

I created a script that reloads my page when I resize it. However when I open up my console, Chrome considers that my page is resized, and reloads it.

Is it possible to not reload my page when I open up my console?

Comment: Why in the name of all that's holy do you reload the page when it's resized? That must be incredibly annoying for your visitors. To answer your actual question - yes, open the console in a separate window. But you should *definitely* stop reloading the page on resize.

Comment: detach the console

Comment: I'm guessing you do it for reponsive things, don't, you have other ways to do what you need. you can leave the console open and refresh the page, or detach it like @JaromandaX said (dev options)

Comment: you can also check if the height is changed and not reload the page, reload only when width is changed.

Comment: try using a break point

Answer (score 0):

After opening the dev console Click the vertical ellipsis button ( ⋮ ) then undock the console.
After you can see what is going on with website.

[Here How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6OfK.png)